# Use of @Test in JUnit while data driving

Tags: java, selenium, junit, allure

I am trying to figure out if something is possible (or if I am being a bit silly.)

I have a very simple Excel sheet - 2 columns, one column is a list of search terms, the second column is a list of expected URLS.  I run this via selenium, it will navigate to google, open the Excel sheet, search for the term and if the expected result appears pass the test.  It does this for the three rows in the sheet.  All good.  However, I was hoping to @Test each of the rows - but I can't quite figure out how to achieve this.

Below is the test code, like I said I can't quite get this to work - at present it runs but appears as a single test which has had 3 different searches.

```
@Test
@Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
public void driveDatData() throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException {
    parameters = WebDriverSteps.currentDriver.toString();
    steps.openWebPage("http://www.google.co.uk");

    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\sites.xls");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet s = w.getSheet("Sheet1");

    for (int i=1;i<=s.getRows(); i++) 
    {
        if (i > 1) 
        {
            steps.goToURL("http://www.google.co.uk");
        }

        steps.search(s.getCell("A" + i).getContents());
        Assert.assertTrue("Check the " + s.getCell("A" + i).getContents() + " link is present", steps.checkForTextPresent(s.getCell("B" + i).getContents()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of effort managed to get this working in JUnit using @RunWith. Found a few examples which, while not exactly what I wanted, gave enough insight to get this woring for me with JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

I assume it makes sense for you to have your test data in an external excel sheet? Otherwise the more common approach would be to keep test data within your project as a test resource. Also I think there are various frameworks around that can help you retrieving test data from excel files.

Having said this:

Change your code to populate the test data into a data structure at `@Before`, write different `@Test`s that test different things. This will also separate the retrieval of the test data from the actual test (which is a good things in terms of maintainability and responsibilities). If file reading / performance is an issue, you might want to use `@BeforeClass` to do this only once per test class.

```
@Before
// read file, store information into myTestData

@Test
// tests against myTestData.getX

@Test
// tests against myTestData.getY
```

Comment: Hi Jan,   Yeah it would be better to store the data in an excel sheet (at the moment I am only playing with the concept) however we're potentially talking about a fair amount of data.  I did consider the writing of a ton of different @Test methods, however (in the case of a calculation) I thought I could use a loop to retrieve the data .

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use a loop?

Comment: I'm getting closer to a solution just now - the loop didn't work as expected - the output isn't what I wanted - so will use @RunWith and build it up that way.  This is only to improve readability of the results in allure.

Answer (score 0):

For any good test code complexity should be 1. Any loops should be replaced by parameterized tests. Please take a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests.

Comment: I am currently using this:     `@Parameters
    public static Collection<String[]> addedData () {
     return Arrays.asList(new String[][] { {"apple", "www.apple.com"}, {"MSN", "www.msn.com"}, {"yahoo", "https://uk.yahoo.com"}, });` However, I still want the source data (which can change) to be stored externally, so loops would be needed to somehow parse this excel file and create the `@Parameter` from it.
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add **Feed4JUnit** to your project.
It is highly configurable and the only library I know that can do parameterized JUnit and TestNG tests out-of-the-box with Excel support.

[Feed4Junit](http://databene.org/feed4junit.html)

```
@RunWith(Feeder.class)
public class AddTest {

    @Test
    @Source("http://buildserv.mycompany.com/wiki/myproject/tests/add.xls")
    public void testAdd(int param1, int param2, int expectedResult) {
        int result = MyUtil.add(param1, param2);
        assert result == expectedResult;
    }
}
```

This example comes straight form the Feed4Junit site.

Important to note the parameters are read left-to-right.

Each row is a test and must have valid values in each column, i.e. if a column has the same value for 3 rows then it needs to appear in each row.